# Passing an array to a function that takes various arguments

Tags: laravel

I have two funtions:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
```

and

```
public function hasAnyRole(...$roles){
```

I call the first function to check if the user has the required permissions:

```
$this->middleware('roles:request,delete');
```

The $roles variable is correctly created and has an array consisting with the values request and delete. In my next move I am calling the function hasAnyRole where again I can pass various arguments but when I call it with the already created array it gets interpreted as on value:

```
$request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
```

I also tried it with the implode command but I still receive one array with only one value:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "request,delete"
]
```

Anyone knows how I can transform the array to that it gets called like this:

```
hasAnyRole("delete", "request")
```

Thanks
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the array to `hasAnyRole()` which takes an array as parameter, which means you can passing a list of array values. 
Assuming your function is like this

```php
 hasAnyRole($roles){
    ....
 }
```

But what you are trying to do is `handAnyRole($role1, $role2, ...)` which is not possible. You would need to do something like this

```php
hasAnyRole($roles){
    foreach($roles as $role){
       if(doCheck($role)){
         ...
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is I am also calling the hasAnyRole function from a blade: hasAnyRole("delete", "request") to show the available menus

Comment: Ok, I think the trick is to call in the blade with [] and the function then without the tree dots. Everything should work like this. Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert $roles to array using

```
$roles="request,delete";

$roles_array=explode(',',$roles);
```

then for pass as separate args you can do it like this

```
hasAnyRole(...$new_roles); //hasAnyRole('request','delete',and more);
```